# ¿Cómo resolver estas dos advertencias de seguridad en Laravel 9?

Tags: laravel, symfony, guzzle

Ejecuté el comando `composer audit` en mi proyecto y me muestra dos advertencias de seguridad, buscando en Google una tiene solución pero no sé si debo modificar directamente el archivo.

Las advertencias:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para la primera encontré este enlace `https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-wxmh-65f7-jcvw` que no tiene solución aún

Para la segunda encontré esta solución `https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/d2f6322af9444ac5cd1ef3ac6f280dbef7f9d1fb`, no sé si debo acceder al archivo que está en esta ruta `miproyecto\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\HttpCache\Store.php` y modificarlo directamente, no afecta en nada el buen funcionamiento del framework?

Comment: Creo que la única opción posible de poder resolver estas advertencias es actualizando dichos paquetes en Laravel y si no es posible, entonces actualizar tu proyecto por completo, porque como comentan, esto afecta a ciertas versiones en específico. Imaginaría que es algo que no ocurre en versiones más recientes

Comment: Gracias, uso la versión 9. Voy a intentar actualizar las versiones de los paquetes a ver.

Comment: Actualizar los paquetes fue suficiente, gracias!